# Subset table based on strings present in multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
> df
               Col1                 Col2             P_value  
              Cell1                Cell2               0.001      
              Cell2                Cell1                0.05      
              Cell4                Cell1                0.01     
              Cell5                Cell2                0.03        
              Cell2                Cell3               0.008      
              Cell1                Cell4               0.008
```

I want to subset to a new dataframe, in which only strings present in BOTH `Col1` and `Col2` in both orders. So here, `Cell1` and `Cell2`, when matched, appear in both Col1 and Col2.

```
> df
               Col1                 Col2             P_value  
              Cell1                Cell2               0.001      
              Cell2                Cell1                0.05 
              Cell1                Cell4               0.008 
              Cell4                Cell1                0.01
```

So here, `Cell1` and `Cell2`, when matched, appear in both Col1 and Col2. Same for Cell1 and Cell4. This never happens for other strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Col = str_c(pmin(Col1, Col2), pmax(Col1, Col2))) %>%
  filter(duplicated(Col)|duplicated(Col, fromLast = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-Col)
```

---

Or may do

```
 df %>%
   add_count(pmin(Col1, Col2), pmax(Col1, Col2)) %>% 
   filter(n > 1) %>% 
   select(names(df))
```

-output

```
   Col1  Col2 P_value
1 Cell1 Cell2   <0.05
2 Cell2 Cell1   <0.05
3 Cell4 Cell1   <0.05
4 Cell1 Cell4   <0.05
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell4", "Cell5", "Cell2", 
"Cell1"), Col2 = c("Cell2", "Cell1", "Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3", 
"Cell4"), P_value = c("<0.05", "<0.05", "<0.05", "<0.05", "<0.05", 
"<0.05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is over-simplifying, but ...

```r
df %>%
  filter(Col1 %in% Col2 & Col2 %in% Col1)
#    Col1  Col2 P_value
# 1 Cell1 Cell2   <0.05
# 2 Cell2 Cell1   <0.05
# 3 Cell4 Cell1   <0.05
# 4 Cell1 Cell4   <0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on `inner_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df, df[-3], by = c("Col2" = "Col1", "Col1" = "Col2")) 

#>    Col1  Col2 P_value
#> 1 Cell1 Cell2   0.001
#> 2 Cell2 Cell1   0.050
#> 3 Cell4 Cell1   0.010
#> 4 Cell1 Cell4   0.008
```